# Create an odd byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I am after some help in creating a byte array that will allow the following:

- bytes 1-2 : An integer, n, that specifies the length of the file name
- 3 - n+2 : The name of the file
- n+3 - n+10 : The last modified date of the file
- n+11 - n+12 : Integer with value 1
- n+13 - n+16 : long integer with the length of the file data
- n+17 - n+20 : long integer with value 0
- n+21 - end : The file's content.

I already have the following code which places the file into the byte array, but this is on the the last portion.

```
byte[] filebytes;
st.birth_certificate = detail[4];
downloadfile.HTML = detail[4];
downloadfile.fileName = downloadfile.GetFileNameFromUrl(st.birth_certificate);
downloadfile.toLocation = @"c:\temp\" + downloadfile.fileName;
if (downloadfile.DownloadFile())
{
    filebytes= File.ReadAllBytes(downloadfile.toLocation);
    st.birth_certificate_file = filebytes;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Better to do with BinaryReader.  I'm not sure if numbers are hex values or ascii numbers (or Big/Little Endian) so I'm doing a little guessing. Code may need some minor tweaks  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL = "enter you url here";
            FileStream sReader = File.OpenRead(URL);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(sReader);

            int filenameLength = reader.ReadInt16();
            string filename = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(filenameLength));
            int year = int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(4)));
            int month = int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(2)));
            int day = int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(2)));
            DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            short number1 = reader.ReadInt16();
            int number2 = reader.ReadInt32();
            byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes((int)(reader.BaseStream.Length - reader.BaseStream.Position + 1));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I have copied your code exactly as shown as it does not seem to work.  I have replaced the "enter you URL here" to c:\\temp\\file_name.pdf and an error occurs at the string filename line.

Am I missing something

Comment: Check the value of filenameLength.  The length is probably larger than the file size.  I don't know if the actual number the bytes are backwards (little/big endian) or the length is ascii.